# Sitecore WebForms/MVC site migration to JSS

Tags: jss, migration

Can somebody share known pitfalls when migrating `WebForms` or `MVC` site that uses `Personalization/AB Testing/Analytics/Sitecore Forms/EXM/SXA` etc. to `JSS`?

Any known limitations?

Sitecore versions: `9.2` and higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No big limitations but it all depends on your application. Here are some guides to help you out

https://blog.vitaliitylyk.com/guide-on-refactoring-your-sitecore-solution-to-sitecore-jss/

http://joost-sitecore.blogspot.com/2019/11/get-off-my-lawn-journey-from-sitecore.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/limitations-and-workarounds-for-static-generation-of-mvc-apps-with-jss.html

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are not generally recommended on SSE. The answer should contain all the information without having to leave the site. [Links as references](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) are great, but they should never be the only information in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Vinu Krishnaswamy, first blog post looks good!

Answer (score 2):

I also want to share an additional blog post:

```
Converting Sitecore MVC sites to Jamstack with Headless Services and JSS – Next.js
```

https://miguelminoldo.fr/2022/03/17/converting-sitecore-mvc-sites-to-jamstack/